# With SDL 2.0 in C, how do I make a rectangle fade in and out?

Tags: c, sdl

I'm making a small 2D game and I'm trying to make a rectangle fade from transparent (white) to it's original color and then back to white again and just continue to pulse from white to it's color and back. For example:

white -> fade to red -> red -> fade to white -> repeat...

I've made my rectangle with:

```
SDL_Rect rect;
```

I then set the color and drawn the rect to the screen (after setting it's x and y position and size):

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 51, 0, 255);
SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
```

But I don't know what the last parameter is (alpha). In the wiki, the documentation for the SetRenderDrawColor is:

```
int SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(SDL_Renderer* renderer,
                       Uint8         r,
                       Uint8         g,
                       Uint8         b,
                       Uint8         a)
```

Where 'a' is the alpha value (and r, g, b is red, green, blue). Is this what allows me to change the opacity of the color? If I have a loop and each frame I just have a variable changing between 0 and 255 and make that the "alpha" value would that allow my to change the transparency and make th rectangles color "pulse"? How can I do this?

Do I have to make my rectangle a texture? Is there a way to turn this feature on for me to change the alpha value?

EDIT: I realised I was't using RenderClear in the loop! THat fixed the problem.

Comment: You need to use [SDL timers](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryTimer) with a callback changing opacity. Alpha is the opacity (0 = transparent, 255 = fully opaque)

Comment: See [RGBA color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) wikipage and read about [alpha channel](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-DataRep.html#DR.Alpha-channel)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Okay I have no idea how to do that but I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Don't edit answers into your question. If you found an answer by yourself, you are allowed to [post it as one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the alpha value.  Alpha represents the transparency.  Maximum value means it is opaque (not transparent at all), minimum value of zero means it is completely transparent (not visible at all).  In this case, 255 means it is not transparent.  If you set it to say, 128, than it would be 50% transparent.  To fade in and out, adjust the alpha value.

Comment: I'm doing this and also setting it up using SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND) and using a variable that changes each loop iteration called "opacity" here: SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 51, 0, opacity); and then filling the rect with SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);

Comment: ^ That works, but I cannot lower the transparency dynamically with the opacity variable. It only increases but won't decrease.

Comment: Are you clearing the surface before you draw to it?  It won't decrease if you keep redrawing over the same spot without clearing it first.  That's the only circumstance I can think of where it would increase but not decrease.